# More than One Internet Connections on Windows

Tags: windows, internet-connection

I currently have two different Internet connections: one is a 1 Mbps 3G connection (very low downtime but unstable bandwidth, fair latency, mobile, already NAT-ed at ISP-level, tethering allowed, 2 GB monthly allowance) and the other is a cheap 5 Mbps Cable connection (stable bandwidth but fairly high downtime, high latency, not NAT-ed, no allowance). I connect to the 3G network by means of tethering, with my phone acting as modem through Bluetooth, and to the Cable via a WiFi router.

I want to use both connections on the same computer but for different purposes at the same time. Specifically, I want to use the 3G connection for usual Internet activities like browsing, e-mail, IM and whatnot, and the Cable connection for bandwidth-intensive activities like large file downloads via HTTP and BitTorrent, video streaming and the likes.

How can I do this on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have some luck with a piece of freeware software called [**ForceBindIP**](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/).  It allows you to bind different programs to different network adapters.

> ForceBindIP is a freeware Windows application that will inject itself into another application and alter how certain Windows Sockets calls are made, allowing you to force the other application to use a specific network interface / IP address. This is useful if you are in an environment with multiple interfaces and your application has no such option for binding to a specific interface.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use the 3G connection for usual Internet activities like browsing, e-mail, IM and whatnot, and the Cable connection for bandwidth-intensive activities like large file downloads via HTTP and BitTorrent, video streaming and the likes.

The problem is that the system doesn't know whether a HTTP request belongs to "browsing" or "large downloads" until *after* it establishes the TCP connection, sends the request, and receives a response, at which point it's too late to switch connections.

It may be possible to do this in a proxy server program that would restart the connection completely, but I'm not aware of any existing implementations. Another way is to do it *manually*, by copying the file URL and giving it to a download tool that allows specifying network interfaces (command-line `wget --bind-address=<address>` or `curl --interface=<address>`, where *`<address>`* is your cable connection's IP address).

Most peer-to-peer programs, however, have a configuration option for using a specific network interface; in μTorrent, it's `net.bind_ip` under *Advanced*. Specify your cable IP address. For those programs that don't, see *ForceBindIP* [as suggested by kez](https://superuser.com/questions/296605/more-than-one-internet-connections-on-windows/296611#296611).

In some cases, when the remote end's address is known and static, you can add a host route for it through a specific interface: `route add <remote address> <your cable address>`. It will affect all IP communications.

Comment: Yeah, seems like customizing the routing table is the 'easiest' solution. I did that for a few known IP's, but it was cumbersome. I think I should get a low-power box and make it act as a proxy (although configuration will most likely be time-consuming).

Comment: @Barstow: kez suggested ForceBindIP, which may help with IM and web browsing. You'll still have to somehow reroute big downloads, though.